# query expression self-join

Tags: f#, computation-expression, query-expressions

How can I change this query expression's `join` clause so that I don't have to wrap `parent.ID` in an `option` just to join on a candidate `child.ParentID` which might be `None`?

```
query { for parent in d.People do
        join child in d.People on (Some parent.ID = child.ParentID)
        exists (child.Birthdate <= parent.Birthdate) }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess this model is of the lineage of asexual beings

Comment: Why is the wrapping a problem? It seems to fit the data well.

Comment: I just want to avoid that extra allocation and constructor, as low-overhead as this situation might be.  I wonder if there might be another supported and more efficient syntax that I'm not aware of.

Comment: If this is being translated into SQL and run in the database, why would there be any extra allocations or constructors?

Comment: @uosɐſ if performance is critical, you should not be using linq.

Comment: it's not about performance as much as it is about understanding whether `join` and similar query syntax clauses are as fully expressive as they could be - and that what seem like limitations by syntax really aren't limitations of expression.  In T-SQL, you can have multiple join conditions in a boolean expression tree.  In query expressions, you can have multiple keys with tuples (at the cost of an allocation?) but type conversions, inequality, pattern matching I guess not.

Comment: And to Joel's comment, it seems like more work to be able to detect the use of `option` and translate it to `... IS NOT NULL AND ...`.  Perhaps the loss of resolution there would require a less efficient T-SQL rendering in certain complex queries - or in some *other* situation that evaporates to the same intermediate representation.

Comment: I'm not claiming one thing or the other; but that's what I'm wondering about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like this.  There may be a more elegant syntax for this approach, and I expect in the end it is not going to perform much differently, if at all, but here it is:

```
query { for child in d.People do
        where (child.ParentID.IsSome)
        join parent in d.People on (child.ParentID.Value = parent.ID)
        exists (child.Birthdate <= parent.Birthdate) }
```

I first came up with this, but I wondered whether it implies calling `Value` before filtering out the `None` values:

```
query { for parent in d.People do
        join child in d.People on (parent.ID = child.ParentID.Value)
        where (child.ParentID.IsSome)
        exists (child.Birthdate <= parent.Birthdate) }
```

To  keep parent first and also put the child filter before the join condition, you can do a subquery, but that seemed a worse solution, not better.  If someone knows a way of doing that without the subquery, please add a comment.